# Siesta Swift Casting from ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject> to Array<AnyObject>

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

I am configuring ResponseTransformer of siesta to return array of objects.

```
    service.configureTransformer("/models/*") {
        Model.instantiate($0.content)
    }
```

but somehow when I try to convert them to back to array using `let objects = response.content as! [Object]`
 I got this exception 
`Could not cast value of type 'Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>' (0x382a0a0) to 'Swift.Array<Object>' (0x16f5358).`

Comment: You could inspect the dynamic type of the value wrapped in the optional `response.content` by writing `if let content = response.content { print(content.dynamicType) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map your response, like this

```
configureTransformer("/models/*") {
    ($0.content).map(Model.instantiate)
}
```

And to get later, you can try this way

```
let objects = resource.typedContent() ?? []
```

Comment: Note that you can also do `resource.typedContent(ifNone: [])`. This has the advantage that you can fine-tune the type inference using the `ifNone` param: `resource.typedContent(ifNone: [Model]())`.